# Not able to pass any value in the customer id using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying the below page

https://netbanking.hdfcbank.com/netbanking/

I am not able to send any value to customer ID using selenium web driver. Need a help in this.

My code:

```
public class login { 
   static WebDriver driver; 
   public static void main(String[] args) { 
      driver= new FirefoxDriver(); 
      driver.get("netbanking.hdfcbank.com/netbanking/"); 
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/table[2]/tbody‌
                                   ​/tr/td[2]/table/tbod‌​y/tr[1]
                                   /td[1]/table/‌​tbody/tr[3]/td[2]
                                   /ta‌​ble/tbody/tr[2]/td[2‌​]/span/input"))
      .send‌​Keys("1234"); 
} 
}
```

Comment: You **need** to post your code.

Comment: Hi Brian, Thanks for the reply!

Comment: public class login {
 static WebDriver driver;
 

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  driver= new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.get("https://netbanking.hdfcbank.com/netbanking/"); 
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/span/input")).sendKeys("1234");
 }

}

Comment: I have tried with different elements like By ID, Name etc but failed to locate the element.

Comment: What language are you using?  Looks like `Java`?  Also, what version of `Selenium` are you using?

Comment: yes,  java and version 2.53.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the URL that you are using won't be recognised easily by selenium browser. Change the URL to `"https://netbanking.hdfcbank.com/netbanking/"`

Second, the main page is composed of 2 `Frames` namely `login_page` and `footer`. You are interested in the login_page Frame, so you need to switch selenium's focus to that frame.

To switch focus to the frame, add this line before `driver.findElement()`:

`driver.switchTo().frame("login_page"); //frame() requires either the name or id of frame or it's index`

Third, instead of the xpath that you currently have, use the xpath `"//input[@name='fldLoginUserId']"`. It's short and easy to understand

**Working solution**:

```
driver.get("https://netbanking.hdfcbank.com/netbanking/");             
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
driver.switchTo().frame("login_page");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='fldLoginUserId']")).sendKeys("1234");
```

Comment: Thankyou Jayesh!  I have also tried with frame concept but still failed .i.e. i dont find two frame in that page. please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: try right-clicking on right side of page and click view page source

Comment: Got it. Thank you .

Comment: yes perfectly. Thanks a lot. Need one more help . After this step i need to click on continue button . Below is the actual Xpath

Comment: html/body/form/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]/a/img                                                                                                                  <a ondblclick="return fLogon()" onclick="return fLogon();" href="javascript:void(0)">
<img border="0" style="margin-right:18px;" alt="continue" src="/gif/continue_new1.gif?v=1"/>
</a>    how to get short and clear xpath in this

Comment: @SJR to click on continue button, use xpath `"//img[@alt='continue']/.."`

Comment: Thank you very much Jayesh.